# Search tweets by language and country simultaneously using searchtweets for Twitter's premium API?

Tags: python, twitter

I am using the Twitter's premium API to download tweets restricted to a particular country and language. In order to do this, I am using search tweets, which access the mentioned premium API. However, when I collect the tweets I received an empty list.

I am starting by restricting the search to a given language ('es'), as shown below, and a string. However, this query produces zero matches. When I tried the same but removing the language information from the rule, gen_rule_payload('cr7', from_date='2017-06-03',  to_date='2017-06-04', results_per_call=100), it provides the expected results.

So, my question is how can I query for both language and place_country simultaneously in either searchtweets or any other python wrapper of Twitter's premium API?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Daniel

```
from searchtweets import gen_rule_payload, load_credentials, 
collect_results

premium_creds = load_credentials(filename="filename.yaml",
yaml_key="yaml_key",
env_overwrite=False)

rule = gen_rule_payload('cr7 lang=es', 
                    from_date="2017-06-03",  
                    to_date="2017-06-04",    
                    results_per_call=100)

tweets = collect_results(rule, max_results=100,        
         result_stream_args=premium_creds)

[print(tweet.all_text) for tweet in tweets]

[]
```